# javascript / jquery - setting (this) in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hey all. Basically, I need "(this)" in my function to correspond to this selection:

```
$(".widget .portfolio img")
```

But I want alternative ways of running this function, one when it is cilcked, and one in intervals, like this:

```
function cycle()
{
  var poo = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".poo").html(poo);
}

    $(".widget .portfolio img").click(function() {
        cycle();
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        cycle();

    }, 4000);

});
```

The problem is that when the interval runs, the function's value of "(this)" is that of the setInterval function - but I want it to be the selection I said above... if I could do something like this, it would be ideal:

```
setInterval(function() {
        cycle($(".widget .portfolio img"));
        ...
```

I think I just need a simple something in the function... any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone :) They all work great -- I've gone with the answer with the example that I have gone with. Thanks again.

Comment: You've gone with the answer you've gone with? ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a reference (or a jquery selector) to cycle.

```
function cycle(obj)
{
  var poo = obj.attr("id");
  $(".poo").html(poo);
}
```

or

```
function cycle(sel)
{
  var poo = $(sel).attr("id");
  $(".poo").html(poo);
}
```

then you can use either `cycle($(".widget .portfolio img"))` or `cycle(".widget .portfolio img")` according to which you prefer.

My preference would be passing a reference, as I could then do this:

```
$(".widget .portfolio img").click(function() {
        cycle($(this));
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        cycle($(".widget .portfolio img"));

    }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) or using jQuery 1.4+ [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Using `call()` / `apply()` (the only difference between these is passing arguments to the function).  Every function can be called using call/apply, the first argument will be the context (`this`) for the function call, and the second/more arguments are the arguments to the function.  `apply()` takes the function arguments as an array, where `call()` takes them individually.

```
var $imgs = $('.widget .portfolio img'), imgNum = -1;

setInterval(function() {
   imgNum = (imgNum + 1) % $imgs.length;
   // to simulate cycling through the items for instance?

   cycle.call($imgs.get(imgNum)); 
},4000);
```

### `jQuery.proxy()`

This function is slightly different (and not really applicable to this situation), but can also be used to set the `this` context for a function.  What `proxy()` does is take a function, and returns another function that calls the original function forcing its context to what you specify. [Here's an example](http://dnnbuddy.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/attach-event-handlers-while-context-is-pointing-back-to-a-different-object/) of using `$.proxy()` to map a call to always be in the context of the calling object.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question as stated instead of guessing what the poster wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cycle(me) 
{ 
  var poo = me.attr("id"); 
  $(".poo").html(poo); 
}; 

$(".widget .portfolio img").click(function() { 
        cycle($(this)); 
    }); 

setInterval('cycle($(".widget .portfolio img"))', 4000);
```

Comment: wish I woulda thought of that :)